# как сделать так чтобы в python тип данных был none но при этом автоматически не вычислялcя

Tags: python, типы-данных

я хотел сделать скрипт который при вводе программы автоматически выводит 5 значений Y при 5 заранее установленных значениях X. вот говнокод:

```
alg = 9*x**2-12*x+3

alg = input((x+8)**2-5)
print(type(alg))

def graph():
    x = -2; y_deg2 = (alg)
    x = -1; y_deg1 = int(alg)
    x = 0; y_zero = int(alg)
    x = 1; y_pos1 = int(alg)
    x = 2; y_pos2 = int(alg)
    print('x -2 -1 0 1 2')
    print(f"y {y_deg2} {y_deg1} {y_zero} {y_pos1} {y_pos2}")
graph()
```

я пробовал использовать тип none, но скрипт не смог подставить Х в формулу (оно и понятно)

Comment: ничего не понятно, поточнее напишите что именно надо, какие именно 5 значений? Надо чтоб пользователь сначала ввел 5 значений x и потом будет выведено 5 значений y?

Comment: Возьмите для начала учебник и освойте основы языка